# Open a different preference activity from each list view item

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `ListView` and list items in it. I have an `onItemCLick` set such that when the user clicks on the first list item, it opens a new `Activity` which is a `PreferenceActivity`:

```
Intent p = new Intent(this, Settings.class);            
startActivity(p);
```

When I click on the second list item, it also opens the same `PreferenceActivity` as in the first list item. So if I make any changes to the preferences of the first list item, I see those changes when I click the second listitem. I understand it is basically opening the same `Activity` everytime. Can someone please help how to open different preference activities for each list item click.

I think I should use a `putExtra()` in the `Intent` before opening the `PreferenceActivity`. But I am not sure what to put and how to use it in the `PreferenceActivity`. Can someone please help. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: Doesn't your `PreferenceActivity` persist some settings to your `SharedPreferences` anyways? So you will always see a representation of the same settings on your device. I don't really know what you are trying to achieve but there probably is a better way.

Comment: Dont you want to create another PreferenceActivity? or what are you trying to achieve? do you need the same options but multiple times or different options?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp,@Nanoc, Each list item in the list view is an alarm. So basically each list item has it's own preferences like time, ringtone etc. So I want each list item to open it's own preferences.   I am new to this. So any comments would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: Ah, In that case send a alarm identifier to the PreferenceActivity and load your alarm specific preferences from there?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp, So I can use the position ID of the list item (alarm) as an identifier and send it to preference activity but I don't know how to use it in the preference activity to get that specific preference.

Comment: You'll have to dynamically create preferences in your `onCreate()` of the `PreferenceActivity` depending on the identifier you sent. I'll create an answer. Just a sec.

Comment: If you want to show the same options but store it in a different preferenceFile just change the preferenceKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the identifier for the alarm to your `PreferenceFragment`, retrieve it in the `onCreate()` and dynamically create your preferences from there.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int alarmId = bundle.getString("alarmId");

    PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(getActivity()); 
    setPreferenceScreen(screen);

    PreferenceCategory category = new PreferenceCategory(screen.getContext());
    category.setTitle("Preferences for alarm " + alarmId);
    screen.addPreference(category);

    //For example create a checkbox preference
    CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(screen.getContext());
    checkBoxPref.setKey("checkbox_alarm_" + alarmId);
    checkBoxPref.setTitle("Checkbox for alarm " + alarmId);

    category.addPreference(checkBoxPref);
}
```

Just a reminder you'll probably want to remove all the shared preferences for an alarm if you remove a specific alarm as well.